# Ошибка при попытке создать миграцию в консоли диспетчера задач

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, миграция

Не могу создать миграцию в WebApi Обновил PowerShell но вылезла другая ошибка
вот она:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое ApplicationUser.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(150)")]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
  }
```

ValuesContraller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ValuesController(AutheticationContext context)
        {

        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
    "AllowedHosts": "*"
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "IdentityConnection":  "Server=(local)\\sqlexpress; Database=UserDB; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddDbContext<AuthenticationContext>(options =>

            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection"),

            x => x.MigrationsAssembly("WebApplication")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthenticationContext>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

AuthenticationContext.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class AuthenticationContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AuthenticationContext CreateDbContext(string[] args) { var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AuthenticationContext>(); IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build(); builder.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")); return new AuthenticationContext(builder.Options); }
        public AuthenticationContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
               {

               }
            public DbSet<ApplicationUser>ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так что вас смущает? Вы читали текст ошибки? Есть какие то мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: @tym32167 тогда как ее реализовывать?

Comment: У вас это в первой желтой строчке же написано на первом же вашем скрине

Comment: @tym32167 а после обновления реализацию IDisighnTime надо добавлять?

Comment: я без понятия, я только вашу ошибку прочитал. Так что не проверите - не узнаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо прописать класс IDesignTimeDbContextFactory https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/
и также обновить EF core до 2.2 хватит но лучше до 4 версии